# MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2012) built in keyboard problem

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

My keyboard has suddenly stopped working properly.

I can only write by using the keyboard viewer!

Basically the characters: `ijklmno u` and a few other keys don’t work on the Mac's built in keyboard.

System information:
MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2012)
1.8 GHz Intel Core i5
4 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
Graphics Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536 MB
Mac High Sierra 10.13.1

Also not able to modify system settings for scrolling.

Any solutions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a hardware failure since all the keys that are not working are around one area. You may have to consider using a USB or Bluetooth keyboard with your MacBook Air. Repairing the keyboard may be expensive.

Comment: While I agree, the cost of repairing the Macbook Air could be different based on if the machine is within warranty or not, or if you have some kind of liquid damage (A service provider could provide you with an invoice to replace all components with liquid damage, if applicable)